# Julia Dependencies for PYSR

Tags: python, julia

I am trying to install Julia dependencies for PYSR and I am getting following message. How do I resolve this?

```
JuliaError: Exception 'GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:SSL, Your Julia is built with a SSL/TLS engine that libgit2 doesn't know how to configure to use a file or directory of certificate authority roots, but your environment specifies one via the SSL_CERT_FILE variable. If you believe your system's root certificates are safe to use, you can `export JULIA_SSL_CA_ROOTS_PATH=""` in your environment to use those instead.)' occurred while calling julia code:
Pkg.add([sr_spec, clustermanagers_spec], io=stderr)
```

Trying to run Julia Dependencies for PYSR

Comment: Try setting `export JULIA_PKG_USE_CLI_GIT=true` before starting Julia?